# Use a Composable from a library in a compose-agnostic XML application?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-library

I know that `Composables` can be used in `xml` layouts using `androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`.
But the problem is that the application should include `gradle` compose dependency `androidx.compose.ui:ui` to have access to `ComposeView` class.
[image]
The library which provides the Composable of course contains these dependencies. And furthermore, the library is provided to an app via maven repo, i.e. there I a .pom file with all transitive dependencies listed.
So how can I use a `Composable` from a maven library in an legacy app without having this app to include compose dependencies?